# How do I change Sync Adapter Item Name

Tags: java, android

I want to change the name of Sync Adapter item name. For example, in Sync Adapter item Name is `Contact`
I want to replace it with any other name, such as `My Service`.

[image: Here is example please check]

Comment: but in sync adapter we don't have layout file so where we add textView attribute?

Comment: do share xml code

Comment: <sync-adapter xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:contentAuthority="com.android.contacts"
    android:accountType="com.iqbal.account"
    android:supportsUploading="true"
    android:userVisible="true"
    android:isAlwaysSyncable="true"
    android:label="UserInfo"
/>  Here is XML for sync-adapter

Comment: label attribute not working